# Is updated in transaction value visible to other transactions

Tags: sql, rdbms

I want to update a status in a DB table row and I want this to be immediately visible for other processes/transactions reading the same row. Do I have to put this statement in a separate transaction which will be committed right after the update?

I suppose this depends on the DB engine and isolation level, but as this can change I want my code to handle whatever the DB engine and isolation level is.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions:

1. Use the appropriate transaction isolation level `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED` ([details](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378149%28v=sql.110%29.aspx))
2. Other queries can use `NOLOCK` ([details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx))

Check the links from more details.